# Why does Manim not Render Circuit made with CircuiTikZ Well?

Tags: python-3.x, latex, manim

I wanted to draw logic gates, using CircuiTikZ, in Manim.

Here is the code:

```py
class Diagram(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        diagram = TextMobject("\\begin{circuitikz} \
                            \\draw \
                            (0,2) node[and port] (myand1) {}\
                            (0,0) node[and port] (myand2) {}\
                            (2,1) node[xnor port] (myxnor) {}\
                            (myand1.out) -- (myxnor.in 1) \
                            (myand2.out) -- (myxnor.in 2);\
                            \\end{circuitikz} \
                            ")
        self.add(diagram)
        self.wait()
```

If I run this in any TeX editor, the output is as expected. However, in Manim, this is what I get:
[image: Clearly this is not how it is supposed to look like. This was supposed to be logic gates]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I should've made a bit of research beforehand. Turns out you have to make a few edits to the diagram before displaying it.

Just follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPYmZWTjHoU) video and you'll be fine.

If you are in a hurry, this is the class you'll be using rather than `TextMobject`:

```py
class TikzMobject(TextMobject):
    CONFIG = {
        "stroke_width": 3,
        "fill_opacity": 0,
        "stroke_opacity":1
    }
```